# Do I need to empty the contents of a map in this case to avoid memory leaks

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose I have a class as such

```
struct fooBar
{
   std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<foo> > mp_items;
   ~fooBar()
   { /* Destructor does nothing */ }
};
```

In the above case does the destructor have to mention `mp_items.clear()`
or is it safe without that ?`

Comment: There's [documentation out there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/~map).

Comment: BTW: If possible, prefer using `std::unique_ptr`, they are far more lightweight (and for balance less general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your map is containing shared_ptr, you don't need to take care of memory management. They will automatically be deleted when your map goes out of scope. One important thing to note over here is elements would be deleted only if there reference count reaches 0.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/%7Emap):

> ```
> std::map::~map()
> ```
>
> Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called and the used storage is deallocated.

So no, there is no need to call `clear()` because the map's destructor does it for you.

The only case in which you'd ever have to deallocate memory in the destructor is if you allocated a data member with `new`/`new[]` and want its life to end when the object goes out of scope. In that case you would call `delete`/`delete[]` in the destructor.

However, note that there are memory management containers in the standard library that do it for you, like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` among others.